# import matplotlib ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I'm using the Anaconda Python distribution: Python 2.7 x64 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. Today after `conda update --all` importing matplotlib has broken:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6f467123fe04> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot

C:\Users\felagund\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
 27 from cycler import cycler
 28 import matplotlib
---> 29 import matplotlib.colorbar
 30 from matplotlib import style
 31 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive

C:\Users\felagund\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>()
 34 import matplotlib.collections as collections
 35 import matplotlib.colors as colors
---> 36 import matplotlib.contour as contour
 37 import matplotlib.cm as cm
 38 import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

C:\Users\felagund\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in <module>()
 19 import matplotlib.colors as colors
 20 import matplotlib.collections as mcoll
---> 21 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
 22 import matplotlib.text as text
 23 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

C:\Users\felagund\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in <module>()
 56 
 57 import matplotlib
---> 58 from matplotlib import afm, cbook, ft2font, rcParams, get_cachedir
 59 from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
 60 from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import (

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Do you have any ideas how to roll back to stable version or what to downgrade?

`conda install anaconda` and `conda update anaconda` do not change any packages.
My current conda version is 4.3.30, matplotlib version is 2.1.0.

Comment: What package do you suggest to downgrade and to what version? If you mean roll back to previous revision conda install --revision [revision number], then the comments are "This is buggy. Doesn't work. I lost my packages including numpy"

Comment: I do not recommend anything. Probably you have to try out some combinations. My comment was meant for you to improve the question by stating in how far those suggested methods are or aren't helping.

Comment: Hi @felagund - have you found a solution to your issue? I am also seeing this same problem and reverting to previous versions of python3 and matplotlib have not helped. Interestingly enough, I'm also seeing the same error. I found a related GH issue here: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1672, but that has not been closed yet. With the help of a commenter in that thread, I was able to narrow it down to the following import: `from matplotlib import ft2font`

Comment: @cbcoutinho It seems there is an issue with Anaconda 5 and CNTK.
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/2423#issuecomment-338514540
I personally reinstalled everything with Anaconda 4.4, and matplotlib and CNTK work fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. In my case it was Microsoft CNTK was the culprit. I uninstalled it and issue resolved. 
Platform : Windows 10 (64 Bit)
Anaconda : 5
Python : 2.x

Answer (score 0):

I have the same failure and found a [solution on the net](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/2423#issuecomment-335037415), which I'd like to offer over here:

It seems to be a versioning conflict with `zlib.dll`. For resolution find that file in your python environment. I found two matches - one under `ENV/` and one under `ENV/Library/bin`. I just renamed the root on into `zlib.dll.old` and now it works fine for me.