# I receive an import error saying "DLL load failed while importing _path: The specified module could not be found in pycharm when I run matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

number1 = 1
number2 = 5
number3 = 6
x = [-10,-9,-7,-6,-5,-4]
mid = [(i**2) * number1 for i in x]
mid2 = [i*number2 for i in x]
constant = [number3*1 for i in x]

plt.plot(x, mid)
```

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867474/import-matplotlib-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-no

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ImportError: DLL load failed" in PyCharm w/ conda: how to automatically import conda's PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54766467/importerror-dll-load-failed-in-pycharm-w-conda-how-to-automatically-import)

Answer (score 2):

Download Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that i have multiple python versions (3.10 from clean python installation and 3.9 from Git installation)

I deinstalled Git, deinstalled python 3.10, clean PATH environment variable and reinstalled python.