# Problem with matplotlib when imported with python 3.9: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path:

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, import

First. I am relatively new to this all and I am not that experienced with computer science nor coding. This is my first query here on this board.

I have a problem with importing matplotlib when compiling with python 3.9. I think it doesnt matter what my code does because the traceback of pycharm states that it stopped processing after line 1 when importing matplotlib because `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: module not found`

I think it is either due to me recently reinstalling windows 10 or the interaction between python 3.9 and matlotlib. I tried to compile it with python 3.7 and it worked. I tried it again with 3.8 and a similar error appeared. I already tried deinstalling matplotlib with pip and I already tried deinstalling and reinstalling the python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 compileran pycharm. I didn't find an answer on via search here.

How can I fix it? I could go on with 3.7 but I would like to use 3.9 if it's possible.

Down here is the whole error code.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\KMC_WWSim\KMC_Main.py", line 1, in 
> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
> File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\KMC_WWSim\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line 107, in 
> from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
> File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\KMC_WWSim\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 26, in 
> from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
> File "C:\UsersPycharmProjects\KMC_WWSim\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 82, in 
> from matplotlib import _api, cbook, scale
> File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\KMC_WWSim\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\scale.py", line 18, in 
> from matplotlib.ticker import (
> File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\KMC_WWSim\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 179, in 
> from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
> File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\KMC_WWSim\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 46, in 
> from matplotlib._path import (
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed? Which Python version is referenced on your PATH environment variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66882019/i-receive-an-import-error-saying-dll-load-failed-while-importing-path-the-spe

Comment: Solved. It was the path variable thanks!