# Problem with matplotlib - python 3.11: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path:

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, importerror, dllimport

I have the same case which is mentioned in:
[Problem with matplotlib when imported with python 3.9: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67775252/problem-with-matplotlib-when-imported-with-python-3-9-importerror-dll-load-fai)
but i have one version of python installed (version 3.11) and the path is correct.  I do not know how to solving this problem. Could you help me?

I checked if the library is installed in the correct directory. It's correct. The numpy module works and is in the same directory as matplotlib. I have one version installed - python 3.11. I work with Python's IDLE.

Whole bug is:
"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/simple-plot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 56, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, _cm, cbook, scale
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\scale.py", line 22, in <module>
    from matplotlib.ticker import (
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 138, in <module>
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 49, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu.
```

"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

#### Official Author's Recommendation

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24704

The issue can be worked around by using an additional dependency:

`pip install msvc-runtime`

You can specify this in your requirements like so:

```
msvc-runtime; sys_platform == 'win32'
```

Therefore it will only install for Window's users.

#### Further options

The above didn't work in my case. My context is that I am using a Docker container based on the `windowsservercore-ltsc2022` image.

Instead I installed the vcredist manually (I've included a more verbose set of steps as I use chocolatey. Do refer to the latest chocolatey website for any updated install instructions):

```
# Use powershell
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Install chocolatey
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

# Install matplotlib workaround
# https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24704 # Remove after matplotlib 3.7
RUN choco install -y --limit-output vcredist-all
```